# List of sound objects indexing

Tags: list-manipulation, sound

I am creating a list of sound objects:

```
tones={};
For[j = 0, j <= 40, j++, tones = Append[tones,  Play[Sin[2*Pi*t*500/Exp[-0.1*j/20]], {t, 0, 1}]]];
```

Each element of the list will be an instance of Play[ ] with a different frequency depending on j. However, when I run this code, every element of the list ends up having the same frequency. This is happening because, when I play the sound, it is doing so for the current value of j (41) rather than the value of j when the object was created (1).

Is there a way to create this list so that each element has a different value of j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly know why your version doesn't work, but who wants to use loops anyway? Here's a `Table` version that works:

```
tones = Table[With[{j = j}, Play[Sin[2*Pi*t*500/Exp[-0.1*j/20]], {t, 0, 1}]], {j, 0, 40}]
```

For some reason, putting the `With` in there makes it work, whereas without the `With`, it doesn't. This also makes your code work:

```
tones = {};
For[j = 0, j <= 40, j++, 
  tones = Append[tones, With[{j = j}, Play[Sin[2*Pi*t*500/Exp[-0.1*j/20]], {t, 0, 1}]]]
 ];
```

so there's something about the evaluation sequence of `Play` that is weird perhaps. I suspect the following:

It seems like the value for `j` needs to be injected into `Play` (using `With`) because `Play` has the `HoldAll` `Attribute`, which means that its argument is held until it is evaluated (in this case by being displayed onscreen).

Comment: Thank you! I initially tried the table method as well, but got the same issue and thought perhaps it was related to the way tables are instantiated.

Comment: It seems like the value for `j` needs to be injected into `Play` (using `With`) because `Play` has the `HoldAll` `Attribute`, which means that its argument is held until it is evaluated (in this case by being displayed onscreen).